# MySQL cyrillic(russian) characters

Tags: mysql, cyrillic

I'm trying to get Russian characters to inserted into MySQL table but they are replaced by `?`

I've changed the database collation to `utf8_bin`, i've changed the table collation to `utf8_bin` and the column collation to `utf8_bin`.

When i try to manually put in russian characters i get this message

I can manually put in russian characters and they are accepted.  When i try to import a CSV with russian characters, i still get `?`.  I've saved the CSV with UTF-8 encoding.

How do i solve?

Comment: How you are connected to DB - with PuTTY+console or GUI (which)? There is another setting called Connection charset - see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: Did you just set the collation on the table/column or the character set as well? There are two different settings for that.

Comment: BTW, it is better to use `utf8_unicode_ci` instead of `utf8_bin`. Also, try MySQL Workbench

Comment: see edit.  @JanThomä How do i set the character set in the database to utf-8 in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Well usually you do something like `Create Table Foo (bar Varchar(255)) default Character set utf8, engine innodb;`. This should do the trick. How did you define your tables?

Comment: if you directly write insert query in phpmyadmin itself..is it giving any error or character conversion???if it doesn't give any error then you have to do charset i.e. `mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8')` where $conn is your connection variable

Comment: the table has already been created.  In phpmyadmin where do i change character set.  Also why is `utf8_unicode_ci` better than `utf8_bin`?